# Renaming column names in R using numbers in the pre-existing column names as indices and adding text

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, rename

I have data exported from a survey software into R such that the column names are of the form *Qx_y*, where *x* is the section and *y* is the question number within the section. I want to rename the columns in the form *X.Y*, where *X* is the name corresponding to each section (1=A, 2=B...) and *Y* is the name corresponding to each question number (e.g. topleft = 1, topright = 2 etc.). So, *Q1_1* would become *A.topleft*, and *Q1_2* would become *A.topright*.

From searching the threads it seems that I might need a combination of paste0 and regex commands. Here is some sample data and the two lists of the names:

```
Q1_1 = c(1:3)
Q1_2 = c(1:3)
Q1_3 = c(1:3)
Q1_4 = c(1:3)
Q2_1 = c(1:3)
Q2_2 = c(1:3)
Q2_3 = c(1:3)
Q2_4 = c(1:3)
Q3_1 = c(1:3)
Q3_2 = c(1:3)
Q3_3 = c(1:3)
Q3_4 = c(1:3)
df <- data.frame(Q1_1,Q1_2,Q1_3,Q1_4,Q2_1,Q2_2,Q2_3,Q2_4,Q3_1,Q3_2,Q3_3,Q3_4)
sections = ("A","B","C")
questions = ("topleft","topright","bottomleft","bottomright")
```

(There is probably an easier way to specify this data but I'm new to R.) How can I rename all of my columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach. Probably it is not an easier, but a more gereralizable and transparent way, I think.
I am not sure, if this is a good solution. But as I was questioning the approach myself, I was already writing the code ... so here we are :D

```
# some example data
test_data <- dplyr::tibble(Q1_1=1:3,
                           Q1_2=1:3,
                           Q2_1=1:3,
                           Q2_4=1:3,
                           Q3_3=1:3)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
   Q1_1  Q1_2  Q2_1  Q2_4  Q3_3
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3

# creating named vectors as 'lookup tables'
# values: new values
# names: old values
get_section <- c("A","B","C")
names(get_section) <- c("1","2","3")
get_question <- c("topleft","topright","bottomleft","bottomright")
names(get_question) <- c("1","2","3","4")

# split and recode
section_label <- colnames(test_data) %>%
  stringr::str_match("(?:Q)(.*)(?:_.*)") %>%
  .[,2] %>%
  get_section[.]
question_label <- colnames(test_data) %>%
  stringr::str_match("(?:Q.*_)(.*)") %>%
  .[,2] %>%
  get_question[.]

# rename cols
colnames(test_data) <- paste(section_label,question_label,sep=".")

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  A.topleft A.topright B.topleft B.bottomright C.bottomleft
      <int>      <int>     <int>         <int>        <int>
1         1          1         1             1            1
2         2          2         2             2            2
3         3          3         3             3            3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outer` to create combinations of column names :

```
names(df) <- t(outer(sections, questions, paste, sep = "_"))
```

Comment: Can this solution be simplified                                               `colnames(df) <- c(paste0(sections[[1]], "_", questions), paste0(sections[[2]], "_", questions),paste0(sections[[3]], "_", questions))`

Comment: Yes, you can  use `sapply` over `sections` i.e `sapply(sections, function(x) paste0(x, "_", questions))`